# JRuby won't install gems in correct path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle, jruby

I have issues trying to install gems listed in my gemfile. I had a newer version of JRuby `jruby-9.2.19.0` but ended up uninstalling this version and downloading the `jruby-9.1.17.0` version and set it as the default interpreter.

After checking the environment/path settings with `gem env` I can see the following info:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.14.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.3 (2018-04-20 patchlevel 0) [java]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Users/(my_name)/.gem/jruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/jruby-9.1.17.0/bin/jruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/jruby-9.1.17.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: C:/Users/(my_name)/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: C:/jruby-9.1.17.0/etc
```

So the installation directory is correct:

> `C:/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared`

as expected.

BUT when I run:

`bundle install` the command ends up creating a new directory with the name: `jruby-9.2.19.0` and installs the gems into the path: `C:\jruby-9.2.19.0\lib\ruby\gems\shared\gems\jruby\2.3.0`

I tried `Invalidating Caches` within RubyMine itself and it didn't help.

What could be causing this issue where JRuby/RubyMine wont install in the correct directory even though the gem environment has the correct path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying out for days, I used the bundle config documentation which says to use `bundle config list` to view the set configs.

Through this, I found that the bundler had set a path for where the gems should be installed.

After deleting the config, everything seems to work normally as it should!